# Accept/Reject Button in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, express

I am trying to accept or reject invitations through form elements in html.Here is the code :

```
             <form method="POST">
             <input type="submit" name="accept" id="accept" value="Accept">
             <input type="submit" name="decline" id="decline" value="Decline">
             </form>
```

So whenever I try to accept or reject invitations ,the **Accept** or the **Reject** button should change to **Accepted** or **Rejected**.
I can make that happen using javascript onclick properties.But I am confused on how the response object should handle this in the post route in express js???What should my post route do?
When I click either accept or reject, the page should not reload and only the clicked button should change..

```
    response.send()
    response.redirect()
```

My question is what method should my response object contain so that it achieves above(you can think of the 'add to cart' in shopping sites as example). How do I solve it?

Comment: you can use `action` method. But I doubt that would be effective in your case as that will route to different page. So I think you should go with the `onClick` properties of the buttons.

Comment: Yeah,can you explain it with examples?

Comment: Ok, see the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use JQUERY for this. If not, then I will post a Pure javascript solution for it.

To stop the form from submitting. use`event.preventDefault()`

```js
$("#accept").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior

    //... rest of add logic ( Request to  express js endpoint )
    this.value = "Accepted"
});


$("#decline").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior

    //... rest of add logic
    this.value = "Declined"
});
```

I haven't tested it but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you had only one submit, you could do like this:

```
 <form name="myform" method="POST" onsubmit="onSubmit()";>
             <input type="submit" name="accept" id="accept" value="Accept">
  </form>  

function onSubmit(){
 document.myform.accept.value = 'Accepted';

}
```

However, in your case, there are two `submits` so you should use `onClick` of them

```
  <form name="myform" method="POST" onsubmit="onSubmit()";>
                 <input type="submit" name="accept" id="accept" value="Accept" onclick="acceptFunction()">
<input type="submit" name="reject" id="reject" value="Accept" onclick="rejectFunction()">
    </form> 

function acceptFunction(){
 document.myform.accept.value  = "Accepted";
}
function rejectFunction(){
   document.myform.accept.value  = "Rejected";
}
```

Comment: ok so when I post this(when I click `accept` or `reject`) ,It should stay in the same page and only the buttons should have changed to `accepted` or `rejected`. I will edit the question..